# Converting the output of subprocess.check_output() into a dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary, subprocess

I am running the command `netsh wlan show interfaces` from Python using `subprocess.check_output` and collecting it in a variable.

```
a = subprocess.check_output(["netsh","wlan","show","interfaces"])
```

And it is giving me output as:

```
>>> print a
>>> \r\nThere is 1 interface on the system: \r\n\r\n    Name                   : Wireless Network Connection\r\n    Description            : Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter\r\n    GUID                   : 77cbe2d6-1a1e-41e7-be0a-3f18689c9ceb\r\n    Physical address       : c0:38:96:92:b7:1d\r\n    State                  : connected\r\n    SSID                   : PenguinWiFi\r\n    BSSID                  : 6c:72:20:d2:f9:21\r\n    Network type           : Infrastructure\r\n    Radio type             : 802.11n\r\n    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal\r\n    Cipher                 : CCMP\r\n    Connection mode        : Auto Connect\r\n    Channel                : 11\r\n    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 72\r\n    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 72\r\n    Signal                 : 100% \r\n    Profile                : PenguinWiFi \r\n\r\n    Hosted network status  : Not available\r\n\r\n'
```

I want to get the status of wlan from this output as `"connected"` or `"not connected"`.

For that I want to convert the above string into dictionary and want to use `"state"` as a key so that I can get the value from a key and decide whether `wlan` is connected or not connected.

But when I am converting it to a dictionary its giving error something like this:

```
>>> a_dict = dict(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    a_dict = dict(a)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I am not getting what is the real problem, its with the string or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't simply use regex like:

```
>>> re.search('State\s+: (\w+)', a).group(1)
'connected'
>>>
```

---

If it's needed to covert it to a dict, use [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with some [magic](/questions/tagged/magic) like this:

```
>>> dict(map(str.strip, re.split('\s+:\s+', i)) 
         for i in a.strip().splitlines() if i.startswith('    '))

{'State': 'connected',
 'Hosted network status': 'Not available',
 'Network type': 'Infrastructure',
 'Physical address': 'c0:38:96:92:b7:1d', 
 'GUID': '77cbe2d6-1a1e-41e7-be0a-3f18689c9ceb',
 'Authentication': 'WPA2-Personal',
 'Description': 'Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter',
 'Radio type': '802.11n',
 'Signal': '100%',
 'Connection mode': 'Auto Connect',
 'SSID': 'PenguinWiFi',
 'Channel': '11',
 'Profile': 'PenguinWiFi',
 'BSSID': '6c:72:20:d2:f9:21',
 'Name': 'Wireless Network Connection',
 'Cipher': 'CCMP', 'Receive rate (Mbps)': '72',
 'Transmit rate (Mbps)': '72'}


>>> dict(map(str.strip, re.split('\s+:\s+', i)) 
         for i in a.strip().splitlines() if i.startswith('    '))['State']

'connected'
```

Comment: I got the string directly using regex. Thanks for detailed description.. :)

Answer (score 4):

> I am not getting what is the real problem, its with the string or something else?

You can't just convert a string to a dictionary, even if the string reads like one to a human.

You're going to have to parse that string and pluck the (key, value) pairs from it.

The key would be e.g. "Physical address" and the value "c0:38:96:92:b7:1d"

### netsh has an XML output which is computer readable

> The Netsh commands for the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) enable you
>   The tool then exports the collected data into an XML file
>   that you can examine for clues to the cause of the problem.

Why not use the [XML output](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd735538(v=ws.10).aspx) instead of fragile hacks that may stop working at the tiniest console output format change?

```
netsh wlan export profile folder="PATH_TO_FOLDER" name=PROFILENAME
```

This ought to give you a computer readable file, easily traversable with [Python numerous XML tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python).

### Forming dicts from a list of pairs

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
>   required

This is because `dict` expected a list of (key, value) pairs from which to form a dict. (key, value) has a length of 2 (it's a pair)

e.g.

```
>>> dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bakkal, the description you gave is very good..!